# How can I define operators (+,-,*,/) on if statement in C language?

Tags: c

I want to make a calculator with the C language. When I take input from the user, if it is not from + , -,* or /, I want to print "Please enter a operator". My code is like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){

int sayi1,sayi2;

char operator;

printf("HESAP MAKINESI V1.0\n"); 

printf("Islemi giriniz (+,-,*,/):\n");

scanf("%c",&operator);  

if(operator != char(+,-,*,/)){
    printf("Please use a operator");
    return 0;}}
```

But my code is not working. How can I fix it?

Comment: This `if(operator != char(+,-,*,/))` isn't right: you must check each operator individually. `if(operator != '+' && operator != '-' && operator != '*' && operator != '/'))`

Comment: You have to check for each operator separately and you could use a `switch` statement but I don't know if you're allowed to.

Comment: Another alternative is `if(strchr("+-*/", operator) == NULL)`

Comment: If you would transfer this code into C++ (or compile it with a C++ compiler), you would get an error since `operator` is an reserved keyword there, means it cannot be taken as identifier for an object. Maybe worth to mention.

Comment: *"Please use a**n** operator"* as error message when a mismatching character was putted in, is not useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
if(operator != char(+,-,*,/))
```

Is not proper C syntax.  Character constants are enclosed in single quotes, and you must compare each character individually.

```
if ((operator != '+') && (operator != '-') && (operator != '*') && (operator != '/')) {
```

Here, the logical AND operator `&&` evaluates to true of both operands are true.

Comment: @redokum Glad i could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would rather use  `switch .. case` instead of `if`

IMO it is easier to read and maintain

```
void foo(int ch)
{
    switch()
    {
        case '+':
        case ':':
        case '-':
        case '*':
        case '/':
           /* do something */
           break;

        default:
           /* do something if another chars */
        break;
    }
}
```